# ALB logging to S3 bucket: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elb

Why do I keep getting the following error? I'm simply trying to turn on logging for an application load balancer and specifying an S3 bucket to log to.

[image]

I'm logged in as root and have permissions on the bucket set to allow root (me) to perform all operations.

Answer (score 0):

Does its bucket policy allow Elastic Load Balancing account ID?

[Attach a policy to your S3 bucket - Enable access logs for your Application Load Balancer - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/enable-access-logging.html#attach-bucket-policy)

> For the Regions in the list below, use the following policy, which grants permissions to the specified Elastic Load Balancing account ID.

Comment: Hi @jhashimoto. Thanks for responding. I actually found that and tried it after I posted the question. I will post the policy in the original question.